# Regex match specific string

Tags: javascript, regex, match

What is the regular expression using JavaScript to match anything like this **Base64('xxx', 'xxx')**

For example, if I'm trying to match

- Base64('0x28', '6%HA')
- Base64('0x23', '8DLf')
- Base64('0x67', '1)Iz')
- Base64('abc', 'def')

Comment: Please go read [ask]. Show us what actual effort you have made so far to solve this.

Comment: `Base64\s*\(\s*'[^']*'\s*,\s*'[^']*'\s*\)`?

Comment: Thanks @ctwheels this is what i actually need, you saved me